# Linear Algebra: Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 4 &  2\\
0 & 2 & 1\\
3 & 5 & 3
\end{pmatrix}, \quad B=\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
2\\
3
\end{pmatrix}.$$
$A$ is $3\times3$ matrix and $B$ is $3\times1$ matrix. Using these two matrices, I have to answer the following $3$ questions.

1. Find $L$ and $U$ that satisfy $A=LU$
2. Find $Y$ that satisfies $LY=B$.
3. Find $X$ that satisfies $UX=Y$.

I don't even know how to start these questions...
Plus, I apologize for not knowing how to write a matrix in this website.

Comment: What are the conditions on $L,U,Y$ and $X$ (what dimension, what vector space)?

Comment: Can it be that you missed the course on $LU$ decomposition ?

Answer (score 1):

Find the reduced echelon form of $$A=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 4 &  2\\
0 & 2 & 1\\
3 & 5 & 3
\end{pmatrix}$$

That is your $U$

Now you can find your $L$ easily from $A$ and $U.$